# Date not showing in my Excel file which is created on Nodejs with Exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

```
app.get("/get_report", upload.any(), function(req, res) {
  var options = {
    filename: './streamed-workbook.xlsx',
    useStyles: true,
    useSharedStrings: true
};

var workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet');
worksheet.columns = [
    { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
    { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32 },
    { header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'DOB', width: 10 }
];

worksheet.addRow({id: 1, name: 'John Doe', DOB: new Date(1970,1,1).toString()});
worksheet.addRow({id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', DOB: new Date(1965,1,7).toString()});
worksheet.commit();

workbook.commit().then(function(){
    console.log('xls file is written.');
});
});
```

This is my api and what i find after opening the excel file that is created is that i see the columns of DATE empty instead of the data i defined here.

[image: see this image]

Comment: remove .toString() from code after the new Date() function. Please let me know if this work for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your xls document viewer. I've copied your code and ran on my local machine than the xls file is created. Than viewed the file with WPS Spreadsheets.

[image]